# Pandas .DAT file import error with skip rows

Tags: python, pandas, import, data-files

I am trying to break a huge data file into smaller parts. I am using the following scripts -

```
 df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None,encoding='latin1',sep='\t',nrows=100000, skiprows = 100000)
```

but I see that skip rows argument skips  around 200000 rows instead of 100000 can anyone tell me as to why this is happening

Comment: why not just specify a `chunksize=100000` which will return you a slice of the df, so you can then split the df for each chunk?

Comment: The actual file is 190 gb I won't be able to read it all into memory at once

Comment: You don't need to with `chunksize` this will just read the next chunksize rows, you can then do whatever you want with that chunk

Comment: So I am implementing chunksize on a sample file of 2.3 gb with 15041273 rows and I am trying to read it using chunksize with the follwoing code 

`tp = pd.read_csv(r'E:\Utkarsh\Test\feed_3068_20160920_20160927.dat',header=None,encoding='latin1', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=100000)
df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
print(df)`

but the df has the entire data loaded into it instead of the 100000 rows of the chunksize. Am I not implementing it right?

Comment: 190 GB file? Sounds like a job for a big data platform like Spark/Hadoop, not Pandas

Comment: Yeah it will ultimately be processed in redshift, but redshift works better with hundred files of 1 gb rather than one 100 gb file. Hence the efforts to break it

Comment: @EdChum Hey man I have it working with chunksize, thanks for nudging me in the right direction. Have a good one!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @EdChum I was able to solve the problem using chunksize with the following code:-

```
i = 0
tp = pd.read_csv(filename,header=None,encoding='latin1', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000000)
for c in tp:
    ca = pd.DataFrame(c)
    ca.to_csv (file_destination +str(i)+'test.csv', index = False, header = False)
    i = i+1
```